# Custom method reference

Tags: java, interface, method-reference

Is it possible to make method reference with parameter in Java?
Give me to clarify:
I want to know is it possible to write some code like this

```
public boolean customEquals(ClassType object) {
     Predicate<MethodReference> compare = (getter) -> {
            return this::getter.equals(object::getter);
        };
    return compare.test(MethodReference);
}
```

Where ClassType is class, where customEquals method is declared
MethodReference is some link to the getter

The main idea is I want to pass method to the interface, and interface should execute this method for current object and for parameter object

Comment: Your question consists of 4 parts, each of them describing or doing something entirely different than the other three. 1) you can not make a “method reference with parameters”, but there is no sense in insisting on a method reference. A lambda expression can easily describe a method invocation with parameters. 2) your code example is trying to compare two method references for whatever reason. The objects created for method references have an unspecified identity and comparing them has an unspecified result. 3) there is no “customEquals” in your code. 4) Nothing in 1-3 matches that “main idea”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to your point

> The main idea is I want to pass method to the interface, and interface should execute >this method for current object and for parameter object

It is possible, with reflection to pass method for execution. Refer the below code section:

```
package org.test;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public interface SimpleInterface {
    
    public Object exec(Method method, Object param0, Object param1);

}//interface closing
```

The interface has a method, which takes a Method as paramert

```
package org.test;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class SimpleClass implements SimpleInterface{
    
    public Integer simpleMethod(Integer a, Integer b) {return a+b;}

    @Override
    public Object exec(Method method, Object param0, Object param1) {
        
        Object retVal=null;
        
        try{retVal=method.invoke(this, param0, param1);}catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    
    return retVal;
    
}//exec closing
```

}//class closing

The interface implementation along with another method, which will be passed for execution.

```
package org.test;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class SimpleTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        
        SimpleClass obj=new SimpleClass();
        Method method=obj.getClass().getMethod("simpleMethod", Integer.class, Integer.class);
        
        Object val=obj.exec(method, new Integer(1), new Integer(2));
        
        System.out.println(val);

    }//main closing

}//class closing
```

The class that gets a method reference and passes to the interface for execution.

The above uses reflection to achieve the functionality.

NOTE: The above example is with JDK8

Comment: Note: all wrapper type constructors are deprecated since Java 9. `new Integer(1)` should be `Integer.valueOf(1)`, as this leverages the integer cache.

Comment: @MCEmperor, noted :)

Comment: @Ironluca Sry, but I didnt get the point. As I see, you pass method and 2 values into exec() method and then this method will be called with 2 values as parameters. But I need, that this method was called from 2 params. for example:
exec(method, obj1, obj2) {
    Value value = obj.method() + obj.method(); 
}
Your answer helped me to understand how I can do it, thx

Comment: Yes, you can call the method on any object of the class, from which the method is. The actual object also can be passed as a parameter, on which the method needs to be called.